# When NOT to use a class / member variable?

Tags: object-oriented, python, object-oriented-design, class-design, class

I am trying to learn **WHEN NOT** to use:

- classes
- member variables

---

### HERE IS THE CODE

---

**access_point_detection_classes.py**

```
from scapy.all import *

class Handler :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.wap_list = []
        self.TempWAP = None



    def process_packet_capture(self, packet_capture) :
            for packet in packet_capture :
                if packet.haslayer(Dot11) :
                    if packet.subtype == 8 :
                        bssid = packet.addr3
                        if packet.haslayer(Dot11Elt) :
                            p = packet[Dot11Elt]
                            while isinstance(p, Dot11Elt) :
                                if p.ID == 0 :
                                    essid = p.info
                                if p.ID == 3 :
                                    channel = ord(p.info)
                                p = p.payload

                            self.TempWAP = WirelessAccessPoint(bssid, essid, channel)

                            if self.check_for_duplicates() == False:
                                self.wap_list.append(self.TempWAP)

    def check_for_duplicates(self) :
        for w in self.wap_list :
            if self.TempWAP.bssid == w.bssid :
                return True
        return False

class WirelessAccessPoint :
    def __init__(self, bssid, essid, channel) :
        self.bssid = bssid
        self.essid = essid
        self.channel = channel
```

**access_point_detection.py**

```
from scapy.all import *
from access_point_detection_classes_module import *

def main() :

    H = Handler()

    packet_capture = sniff(count = 50)

    H.process_packet_capture(packet_capture)

    for w in H.wap_list :
        print w.bssid
        print w.essid
        print w.channel
        print '++++++++++++++++++++++++'




    # enable_managed_mode('wlan0')

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

---

### HERE ARE MY THOUGHTS

---

I am mostly sure I know **WHEN** to use a class and member variables. Look at my second class `WirelessAccessPoint`. The perfect need for a class in my opinion.

- I need multiple objects of this type
- Easier management of the data that comes along with this type

That's great, but look at my first class `Handler`. To be honest, I mostly created it so I could practice OOP. It does come in handy when I need to access `wap_list`. However, I initialize it without passing parameters for the constructor. Is that defeating the purpose? It seems that I could create all the methods of this class with only the `self` parameter to them. For instance ( haha ) I could make `packet_capture` a member variable of `Handler` and have the method `process_packet_capture()` take the parameter `self`.

At this point I feel like if I do not set some ground rules for myself I will try to make everything a class and everything a member variable and I will never pass a parameter besides `self` ever again!

Comment: When the costs outweigh the benefits.

Comment: @Robert What are the 'costs' of using a class / member variable?

Comment: Mutability, overall increase in complexity, increased storage requirements, increased need for testing, increased need for documentation, higher maintenance costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I initialize it without passing parameters for the constructor. Is that defeating the purpose?

No, absolutely not.  Handler, maybe misnamed, but in a sense it represents a collection object, which is perfectly reasonable without constructor parameters.  A collection object maintains some state for it's duration, and, many collections are created with an initially empty set.

However, what I don't necessarily like is the use of a member variable for the short-lived state of TempWAP.  I think a local variable and some parameter passing would be better here, no?

Maybe the example doesn't make it clear that TempWAP is otherwise used in your more complete implementation, or, as another alternative, you might actually have two classes here that are being conflated (one shorter lived and one longer lived), but based on what I can see in the question, I'd go for local variable instead of member variable here.

The point is that the lifetime of the two member variables in Handler seems inconsistent.  So, these member should be differentiated, either one using a local variable, or in another class (overkill, though perhaps).  To reiterate, when all your member variables in the same class have the same useful lifetime, you have a better class than otherwise.

Comment: `TempWAP` is used throughout the for loop. However, it is completely replaced and assigned with each iteration of the loop. Also, no other method of the class uses it. While `wap_list` is used in several methods as well as being appended to ( not reassigned ). Is this the reasoning?

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use classes and or member variables when they are not needed. As soon as you need them, well, use them.

I'm serious.

Answer (score 2):

A variable should always have the smallest scope and the shortest lifetime possible. Therefore a class member is preferable to a global variable, and a local variable or parameter is preferable to a class member.

In your example, `TempWAP` is only used inside the execution of `process_packet_capture()` and could therefore be changed to a local and passed as a parameter to `check_for_duplicates()`. As a member variable, it is available after the execution, but does not have any useful value. `wap_list` on the other hand is accessed after the execution, so this has to be a member.

But depending on how you use `Handler` you could decide to rewrite  `process_packet_capture()` to a stand-alone function which returns `wap_list`. This would make it simpler to use in my opinion, but this honestly comes down to preference. Some like to follow an OO paradigm throughout, while I personally prefer side-effect free stand-alone functions when possible.

The `packet_capture` variable is only used as input to `process_packet_capture()`, so given the above principles I see no reason to turn it into a member.

I do see a slight risk with having `wap_list` as a member rather than a return value. It means you might mistakenly access `wap_list` before `process_packet_capture()` is called, and if you call `process_packet_capture()` multiple times, `wap_list` will contain the *accumulated* results of all calls. This might be what you intend, but if not, then having it as a return value rather than member avoids this risk of misuse. Alternatively, you could have a `packet_capture` as a argument to the *constructor* and call `process_packet_capture(packet_capture)` directly in the constructor. This way you still have `wap_list` as a member but avoid the risk of misuse.